# How to use LaTeX templates for creating academic papers in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

There are some very nice LaTeX templates for academic papers at overleaf.com: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/academic-journal#.Wr8-mYhubIU. Is there a way to copy the code from there to R Markdown to be able to produce PDFs and other types of documents?

Comment: Check the `rticles` package: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles

Comment: I did check that. There are very few templates compared to what's available at overleaf.com. It's also not easy to change the formatting as much of the code seems to be behind the scenes compared to what is available at overleaf.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `R Sweave`:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr

You should be able to copy and paste with minimal changes.